# Is it possible to make margin notes in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, marginnote

Is it possible to make margin notes in moderncv? Its not working for me nor the todo package.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried in a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg What makes you say that question is a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hmm ... I just figured since it was about margin notes but I guess it isn't a duplicate but rather related... I'll delete my suggestion.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Please check more carefully before voting to close,  that two questions are about the same topic is of course *not* the same as the two questions being duplicates.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sure. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

I just grabbed a resume from one of my other answers, so I am sorry it is a bit large.  the approach is most certainly **not** perfect, because it can cause some vertical displacement if called in vertical mode.  But here is what I did in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tabto,xcolor}
\newcommand\mnote[2][0pt]{\leavevmode%
  \tabto*{\dimexpr#1-2cm}\smash{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{%
    \scriptsize\color{red}#2}}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}
```

Then, in the document

```
\mnote[x-shift]{margin note with 1.5 cm width}
```

Here is the MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.11 (19/6/14)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template requires the moderncv.cls and .sty files to be in the same 
% directory as this .tex file. These files provide the resume style and themes 
% used for structuring the document.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{tabto,xcolor}
\newcommand\mnote[2][0pt]{\leavevmode%
  \tabto*{\dimexpr#1-2cm}\smash{\parbox[t]{1.5cm}{%
    \scriptsize\color{red}#2}}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 \firstname{John} % Your first name
 \familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% % All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
 \address{123 Broadway}{City, State 12345}
 \mobile{(000) 111 1111}
 \phone{(000) 111 1112}
 \email{john@smith.com}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours}  % Arguments not required can be left empty
\cventry{2007--2010}{Bachelor of Business Studies}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 7.5}}{Specialized in Commerce
\mnote[-2.3cm]{I have Lots of it, you will see!}}

\section{Masters Thesis}

\cvitem{Title}{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?}}
\cvitem{Supervisors}{Professor James Smith \& Associate Professor Jane Smith}
\cvitem{Description}{This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience\mnote[16cm]{I forgot my first job... settled Jamestown, 1607}}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.
\newline{}\newline{}
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2010--2011}{Summer Intern}{\textsc{Lehman Brothers}}{Los Angeles}{}{Rated "truly distinctive" for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Miscellaneous}

\cventry{2008--2009}{Computer Repair Specialist}{Buy More}{Burbank}{}{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Awards}

\cvitem{2011}{School of Business Postgraduate Scholarship}
\cvitem{2010}{Top Achiever Award -- Commerce}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer skills}

\cvitem{Basic}{\textsc{java}, Adobe Illustrator}
\cvitem{Intermediate}{\textsc{python}, \textsc{html}, \LaTeX, OpenOffice, Linux, Microsoft Windows}
\cvitem{Advanced}{Computer Hardware and Support}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Communication Skills}

\cvitem{2010}{Oral Presentation at the California Business Conference}
\cvitem{2009}{Poster at the Annual Business Conference in Oregon}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\mnote{Run, Jane, run!}
\cvitemwithcomment{English}{Mothertongue}{}
\cvitemwithcomment{Spanish}{Intermediate}{Conversationally fluent}
\cvitemwithcomment{Dutch}{Basic}{Basic words and phrases only}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists

\mnote{Psst! Guess what I enjoy?}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Piano}{Chess}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Cooking}{Dancing}
\cvlistitem{Running}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]